# Trouble accessing private folder in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

My web2py application is designed to use a json key from a file stored in my 'private' folder. However, I am having issues accessing this file because request.folder returns None.

This is the bit of code that isn't working for me:

```
import os
from gluon.globals import Request


def my_function():    

    request = Request()

    json_file = open(os.path.join('request.folder', 'private', 'quote_generator.json'))
```

Comment: I assume `request.folder` is a relative reference to that file in your directory. While web2py is executing, you are probably not in the directory where request.folder is located.

Comment: Is the above a function in a web2py controller (designed to handle responses to HTTP requests), or is this a script that is not part of a web2py application designed to be run outside the context of an HTTP request?

Comment: The function is in a Python script in the modules folder and is then called by a controller.

How can I link to the file in the private folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For code inside a web2py application that will be handling HTTP requests, you should not be creating your own `Request` object -- the web2py execution environment already includes a `Request` object and populates it with a number of attributes, including `request.folder` (when you create a new `Request` object from scratch, it does not have a `folder` attribute).

If a function in a module needs access to the `request` object, you should either pass it explicitly as an argument or use the method described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Accessing-the-API-from-Python-modules):

```
from gluon import current

def my_function():
    json_file = open(os.path.join(current.request.folder,
                                  'private', 'quote_generator.json'))
```

Alternatively, passing `request` as an argument:

```
def my_function(request):
    json_file = open(os.path.join(request.folder,
                                  'private', 'quote_generator.json'))
```

In that case, when calling the above function from a web2py model, controller, or view, you would have to pass in the `request` object.

Finally, note that when you call `os.path.join`, you would not put `request.folder` in quotes, as that would result in the string literal "request.folder" being added to the path.

Comment: Thanks, I used the first option of importing `current` and that worked. I must have put `request.folder` in quotes at some point along the way when I wasn't thinking - not helping things!